# Twitter in Unity

Tags: c#, unity, twitter

I would like to talk to twitter through my unity game.

I found an library for .NET C# that could help, but I am not sure if this is the right way.... The repository for Tweetinvi is here: https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi

I pulled the repository into a project and am getting +999 errors, mostly related to some strange missing libraries (Windows.UI.Core / Windows.UI.Xaml/ System.Threading.Tasks ....)

***My questions:***

1. For those with more Unity experience: does tweetinvi look like something that could be implemented well with the engine for a mobile game? (I know that not all libraries work for mobile, but don't know what the criteria is...)
2. Does anyone know another, more efficient and painless way to retrieve data from twitter in Unity? (Pseudocode, libraries, experience - any comments are welcome!)

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Twitter offers a [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public) which you can access using the [`WWW`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class. No additional libraries are required.

However, in order to use it you need to authenticate via [OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/introduction) and then include the OAuth headers in every request, which isn't that straight-forward.

There is a free packet on the Unity Asset Store named [*Let's Tweet In Unity*](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/536) which claims to take care of OAuth and offer a simple wrapper for the REST API, but I haven't used it, so I can't say if and how well it works.

Comment: I have just tried using the Let's Tweet In Unity plugin after successfully integrating the Facebook SDK into a game in Unity. I cannot seem to post Twitter updates, and looking online other people seem to have this problem - but there are not many straight forward answers unfortunately.